# add another input in php

Tags: php, input, addition

I have a doubt.
I have a file called
login.php that the root of the site.
he has some input login and password

php it is this:

```
<form action="" method="post" style="float: left;">

    <div style="padding-top: 2px; padding-left:2px;"> 
    <input type="text" name="username"  title="Usuário / Login"  value="Usuário / Login" onfocus="this.value='';" /></div>


    <div style="padding-left:2px;margin-top:18px;"> 
    <input type="password" name="password" title="Password" value="Sua senha" onfocus="this.value='';" /></div>


</form>
```

I would use the input file in this folder / acpcode / the code is this:

```
<td style='width: 33%;'>
            <fieldset style='width: 170px; margin: 0px auto;'>
                <form id='login'>
                    <div class='input'><input type='text' id='account' /><span>{$_lang['account']['inputAccount']}</span></div>
                    <div class='input'><input type='password' id='password' /><span>{$_lang['account']['inputPassword']}</span></div>
                    <button>{$_lang['account']['buttonLogin']}</button>
                </form> 
        </fieldset>
        </td>
```

Comment: So what is the problem and what errors are you getting?

Comment: no error. would you like to use the inputs of a page in another

Comment: `{$_lang..` what cms\framework is this ??

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for an include statement. In your file you wish to have that code in you would want to write

```
include '/acpcode/login.php';
```

Here is a link to the php manual page on [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

Comment: Inside the fieldset tag you could do something like `<?php include '/acpcode/login.php' ?>` Then it would put the php code inside that html code and you would be able to view your login form.